# How to specify qt creator from where to read out data

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I want that qt creator read out data from the file as though they from `std::cin`.
That is I want something the

```
cat in.txt type | ./may_executable_file
```

I need it for testing of programs in qt creator not to collect in the console each time the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think about restructuring your program into the testable methods that will read from `istream` instead directly from `cin`. For example:

```
int do_work(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os)
{
    int n, k;
    is >> n >> k;
    os << n << std::endl << k << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   do_work(std::cin, std::cout);
   return 0;
}
```

And now you may have your test unit like:

```
int test_work()
{
    std::ifstream inf("test.txt");
    std::stringstream out;
    do_work(inf, out);

    // Check out for results here.
}
```

Another option is just to use `Custom Executable` in the run settings of the `QCreator`: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.5/creator-run-settings.html.